# How to Pass Bootstrap Styles down to projected content in Angular 7+?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular7

The documentation on Angular content projection seems pretty sparse, but while I have managed to get the content projection to work, it is unclear to me how to pass Bootstrap classes down to the projected content `<ng-content></ng-content>` in the child component, or if it is even possible to do so?

For example, if I have a simple button that I am projecting:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle mr-4" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">My Buttton</a>
```

how do I pass the classes (e.g. `.btn` and `.btn-primary`) down to the projected content so that is properly styled?

Comment: What do you mean pass bootstrap styles down? The projected content will be exactly what you you put in between the components tags and that will include classes.

Comment: You need to import bootstrap in the global stylesheet `styles.css` or add it to styles array in `angular.json` to make it available throughout the application

Comment: @AdrianBrand That's what I expected, but for some reason, it's not rendering.  If I drop it in the same component outside of my component tags, it renders normally as a bootstrap button, but when it is projected, it does not.  I am selecting tag variables for multi-slot -- not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @SouravDutta This has been done already and works fine outside of my projected content.

Comment: Can you recreate the same in a Stackblitz demo ?

Comment: @SouravDutta As I explained below, the problem was that I had set my encapsulation to ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom in an attempt to try to get the new <slot> tags to work, but I backed out of that and forgot to remove the encapsulation.  Once I did that, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

projecting content is just like rendering HTML code to the child component so whatever you put in between child component tag it will render to the ng-content tag in the child. so if your HTML content bootstrap classes then no need to pass classes or style.

working example - [skdroid-ngcontent-content-projection](https://stackblitz.com/edit/skdroid-ngcontent-content-projection)

Comment: Thank you for the example, the problem turned out to be my encapsulation, which had been changed to ShadowDom to try to utilize the newer <slot> tags, but I forgot to change them back when I backed out of that, DOH!